# Running a package from an outside directory - import problem

Tags: python, relative-import

I have a package:

```
mypkg
|-- __init__.py
|-- __main__.py
|-- mod1.py
```

**__main__.py**

```
from mypkg import mod1

def main():
    print("Hello from mypkg main!")
    print(mod1.mod1_msg())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

File `__init__.py` is empty.

I need to run mypkg from specified path for example:

```
python -m mypath.mypkg
```

When I run the mypkg in this way then I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'mod1' from 'mypkg' (unknown location)
```

This could be solved when I change `from mypkg import mod1` to `from . import mod1` but PEP8 recommends absolute imports over relative imports.

Another solution that I found is to add:

```
import sys
from os import path

sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))
```

to `__init__.py` file

Then everything works great.

So the question is: What is the better solution? Using relative imports or manipulate sys.path to get the package run properly or may be exists another solution of this problem?